# How to change string to number and plus 1 with 000 in front of it

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to change string to number and plus 1 with 000 in front of it ( I'm using javascirpt node JS)

```
ex 
const string = "0009"
const newString =  string + 1
```

I want outout 0010

this is what I try

```
const newString = parseInt(string)+1
const ans = '000' + newString
```

the problem is output is 00010 I want 0010

if more number 0 will less like 0999 or 9999

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pad a value with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros)

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon yes thank you I try to find it but I dont know the key word thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

```
const newString = parseInt(string)+1
const ans = ('0000'+newString).slice(-4);
```